# String was not recognized as a valid parameter for DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I'm using this code:

```
var sec = "163516";
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(sec));
DateTime butikDatetime = DateTime.Today.Add(time);
string dateTime = butikDatetime.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss");
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But receive this error for ParseExact:

> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Somebody have an idea what is wrong?

Comment: What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: [Your code works, actually](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q0aNSe) Are you sure your current `fa-IR` culture does not use any `TimeSeparator` other than `:` character?

Comment: @SonerGönül I am using char `:` for `TimeSeparator`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting the `butikDateTime` to dateTime object without culture (framework will use the current thread culture) and later reconverting the using Invariant culture. Can you use Invariant culture while converting butikDateTime to string

```
var sec = "163516";
TimeSpan time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double.Parse(sec));
DateTime butikDatetime = DateTime.Today.Add(time);
string dateTime = butikDatetime.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTime, "dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Updated line 3 as :

```
string dateTime = butikDatetime.ToString("dd-MM-yy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: can you try with setting the 'System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture' in both conversion?